# BeautifulSoup: Finding class value of a multiple nested element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, find

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup (Python) to find the class value in a multiple nested elements like this:

```
<li class="Top Class Name" dataid="60">
  <a class="Name of Sub Class 1" href="www.abc.com" dataid="61">
    <div class="Class2" dataid="62">
        <div class="My Class3" dataid="63"><span dataid="64">This is correct</span></div>
          <div class="My Class4" dataid="65">
            <svg class="My Class5 Cur(p)" width="20" style="vertical-align:bottom;" height="26" viewBox="0 0 24 24" dataon="filled-circle"  dataid="67"><path d="The Path" dataid="66"></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Using `soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class": "Top Class Name"})` I am able to find the top class.
Now what I am looking for is to find the `class` name of the `svg` element. So it should return: `My Class5 Cur(p)` .

How can this be done?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(soup.find("li", attrs={"class": "Top Class Name"}).find("svg")['class'])
```

prints `['My', 'Class5', 'Cur(p)']`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a much simpler solution for what I need. So I accept this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selector `.Top.Class.Name svg[class]` and then get attribute `class`.

Note, when you have spaces in `class=` attribute, the tag has multiple classes. So `class="Top Class Name"` means that the tag is of class `Top`, `Class` and `Name`. That's the same for `<svg class="My Class5 Cur(p)">`.

```
txt = '''
<li class="Top Class Name" dataid="60">
  <a class="Name of Sub Class 1" href="www.abc.com" dataid="61">
    <div class="Class2" dataid="62">
        <div class="My Class3" dataid="63"><span dataid="64">This is correct</span></div>
          <div class="My Class4" dataid="65">
            <svg class="My Class5 Cur(p)" width="20" style="vertical-align:bottom;" height="26" viewBox="0 0 24 24" dataon="filled-circle"  dataid="67"><path d="The Path" dataid="66"></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

svg = soup.select_one('.Top.Class.Name svg[class]')
print(svg['class'])
```

Prints:

```
['My', 'Class5', 'Cur(p)']
```

---

More on [CSS selectors here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My actual top class name is a very long string like: "AA XYZ BB (W12) DAC HAHA KKA1 UHAS T6262 ...HA" it is very difficult to add a period between all them, is this the only way?

Comment: @TJ1 Do you need to use **all** selectors? You can only chose few of them, that are unique in document. For example CSS selector `.AA.DAC` will select this tag.